# Swift SWRevealViewController Menu not showing after segue back to certain page

Tags: objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I used the tutorial from AppCoda to implement the SWRevealViewController into my swift project. Everything in the tutorial works! But, there is a bug that I don't know how to fix:

I can navigate through the pages connected to my SideBarTableView, but if I go from the SideBar to Page A, and the from Page A go to Page B (which is only connected to A all using segues) and then return from Page B directly back to page A, the side bar doesn't swipe out anymore.

Is there a way to reinitialize all the revealcontainer stuff without segue-ing all the back to it?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to initialize it, but I met the same problem as you and what I did is just segue from Page B to the SWRevealViewController instead of SideBar or Page A in your case. And then the sidebar always works.