# self.revealViewController becomes nil and SWRevealViewController Menu not showing after segue back to SWRevelViewController from a certain VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm using the `SWRevelViewController` framework and met this problem while coding. Basically here's the list of my VCs and their classes:
http://mnch.in/ubyB/3g4uqSwl (picture of my story board)

The problem is when user logged in in `UIVC_2`, it goes back to `SWRevelVC` using the segue marked in blue. However, when the `viewDidLoad` method in `UITableVC` gets called

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
NSLog(@"%@", [revealViewController description]);
if (revealViewController) {
    NSLog(@"hey");
    [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

`self.revealViewController` becomes `nil` and therefore the sidebar stops working since it never gets into the if statement and set the target for sidebar button.

However, if I first logged in user, and close the app, and then build and run the app again, `UITableVC` gets showed directly (`UIVC_1`, `UIVC_2` won't pop up),and in its `viewDidLoad` method, `self.revealViewController` is not nil, therefore sidebar works in this case.

Can anyone explain why this happened and how should I fix it so that when I segued from `UIVC_2` to `SWRevealVC`, `self.revealViewController` won't be `nil`? I've been thinking about this for a long time and still didn't get it. Thanks a lot!

**edit:**
Here is a similar question that is not answered either:
[Swift SWRevealViewController Menu not showing after segue back to certain page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652573/swift-swrevealviewcontroller-menu-not-showing-after-segue-back-to-certain-page).
My case suggested that even when you segue all the way back to SWRevealViewController, self.revealViewController is still not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually nevermind I was being stupid, this actually works, the mistake I made is I changed the segue from UIVC_2 to SWRevelVC, but I kept testing using another VC (let's call it UIVC_3) and UIVC_3's segue hasn't been linked to SWRevealVC but instead the navigation controller...